# remove everything up to first occurrence of special characters

Tags: javascript

helloo... i need to remove everything until first occurrence of special charaters..

say i have string like so..

```
let str = `28 Mar 2017 ... helloo ... i need to remove everything until first occurrence of special charaters ...`
```

i need to remove `28 Mar 2017 ...` thus becoming `helloo ... i need to remove everything until first occurrence of special charaters ...`

i did

```
str.split(" ... ").pop()
```

it just remove everything when " ... " occur, instead of first occurrence... it only apply when there have only 1 " ... "

regex is also welcome..

thank Youu..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove part of the string before the FIRST dot with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901022/remove-part-of-the-string-before-the-first-dot-with-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works by using the [`?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark) of regex.

Full regex break down:

- `^` the start of the string
- `.+` match any character unlimited times
- `?` Matches the preceding expression 0 or 1 times
- `(\.\.\.)` `...` where the `.` is escaped by `\`
- the last space of your regex

then use `String.prototype.replace` to replace the set described by regex with an empty string.

[See the regex here.](http://regexr.com/3fk9s)

```js
let str = `28 Mar 2017 ... helloo ... i need to remove everything until first occurrence of special charaters ...`

console.log(str.replace(/^.+?(\.\.\.) /, ''))
```

Answer (score 3):

The naive solution:

```
    var str = "28 Mar 2017 ... helloo ... i need to remove everything until 
             first occurrence of special charaters ...";
    var res = str.substring(str.indexOf('...')+3, str.length);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `split` you should use `shift()` which will remove the first item in an array. `pop()` is removing the last one

```js
let str = `28 Mar 2017 ... helloo ... i need to remove everything until first occurrence of special charaters ...`;

let split = str.split(' ... '); //Split by characters needed
split.shift(); //Shift first index => everything before characters

console.log(split.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` function and pass the regex `[^.]+[\.]+\s*` to replace everything before the first letter after the ... and the optional space

Look, we didn't used the `g` flag here to match only first occurance.

Then, replace it with `''`

```js
var str = '28 Mar 2017 ... helloo ... i need to remove everything until first occurrence of special charaters ...';
console.log(str.replace(/[^.]+[\.]+\s*/,''));
```