# Remove part of the string before the FIRST dot with js

Tags: javascript

I have the next problem. I need to remove a part of the string before the first dot in it. I've tried to use `split` function:

```
var str = "P001.M003.PO888393"; 
str = str.split(".").pop();
```

But the result of str is `"PO888393"`.

I need to remove only the part before the first dot. I want next result: `"M003.PO888393"`.

Someone knows how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: If you know the characters before the first dot are always going to be four, you can try with `substring()`, like so `str.substring(4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution that I can come up with is finding the index of the first period and then extracting the rest of the string from that `index+1` using the substring method.

```js
let str = "P001.M003.PO888393"; 
str = str.substring(str.indexOf('.')+1);
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to match everything from the start of your string up until the first dot `.`, and replace that with an empty string.

```js
var str = "P001.M003.PO888393"; 
var res = str.replace(/^[^\.]*\./, '');
console.log(res);
```

Regex explanation:

- `^` Match the beginning of the string
- `[^\.]*` match zero or more (`*`) characters that are not a `.` character.
- `\.` match a `.` character

Using these combined matches the first characters in the string include the first `.`, and replaces it with an empty string `''`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `splice` function to remove the first entry and use `join` function to merge the other two strings again as follows:

```
str = str.split('.').splice(1).join('.');
```

Result is

```
M003.PO888393
```

```js
var str = "P001.M003.PO888393";
str = str.split('.').splice(1).join('.');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

many way to achieve that:

- by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) function:

```
    let str = "P001.M003.PO888393";
    str = str.slice(str.indexOf('.') + 1);
```

- by using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function

```
    let str = "P001.M003.PO888393"; 
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1);
```

- by using `substr` function

```
    let str = "P001.M003.PO888393";
    str = str.substr(str.indexOf('.') + 1);
```

- and ...

Answer (score 0):

calling `replace` on the string with regex `/^\w+\./g` will do it:

```js
let re = /^\w+\./g
let result =  "P001.M003.PO888393".replace(re,'')
console.log(result)
```

where:

- `\w` is word character
- `+` means one or more times
- `\.` literally `.`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with the non-greedy quantifier [`*?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Quantifiers#types):

```js
> 'P001.M003.PO888393'.replace(/.*?\./, '')
'M003.PO888393'
```